# insert data and avoid duplication by checking a specific column

Tags: sql, duplicates, mariadb, insertion

I have a local db that I'm trying to insert multiple rows of data, but I do not want duplicates. I do not have a second db that I'm trying to insert from. I have an sql file. The structure is this for the db I'm inserting into:

```
(db)artists
    (table)names->     ID  |  ArtistName  |  ArtistURL  |  Modified
```

I am trying to do this insertion:

```
INSERT names (ArtistName, Modified) 
VALUES (name1, date),
       (name2, date2),
       ...
       (name40, date40)
```

The question is, how can I insert data and avoid duplication by checking a specific column to this list of data that I want inserted using SQL?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, mySQl, SQL server?

Comment: I'm using the MariaDB with SQLite enabled from xampp

Comment: How are you feeding the values in from the CSV?  Do you have a script to format into (name1,date) format?

Comment: Yes, all values are in sql format. I use 'import' with an sql file from phpmyadmin. I've gotten it to insert all my data correctly, but I had a bunch of duplicates so I had to rollback

Comment: You can use a `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE b.ArtistName IS NULL` to only insert new records. If you can't join between the two db then stage the records into a separate table first, then do the insert from there.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate what?  Duplicate name?  Duplicate row?  I'll assume no dup `ArtistName`.

1. Have `UNIQUE(ArtistName)` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) on the table.
2. Use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `IGNORE`.

(No `LEFT JOIN`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following the advice of @Hart CO a little bit by inserting all my values into a completely new table. Then I used this SQL statement:

```
SELECT ArtistName
FROM testing_table
WHERE !EXISTS 
(SELECT ArtistName FROM names WHERE 
testing_table.ArtistName = testing_table.ArtistName)
```

This gave me all my artist names that were in my data and not in the name table.
I then exported to an sql file and adjusted the INSERT a little bit to insert into the names table with the corresponding data.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `names` (ArtistName) VALUES
*all my values from the exported data*
```

Where (ArtistName) could have any of the data returned. For example,
(ArtistName, ArtistUrl, Modified). As long as the values returned from the export has 3 values.

This is probably not the most efficient, but it worked for what I was trying to do.